# How to add another language to a Samsung Galaxy Chat physical keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, languages, localization, samsung-galaxy-chat

Having got a Samsung Galaxy Chat (B5330) I'd like to use its physical keyboard to to enter not only english but also central european (czech) and cyrillic (russian) letters (I am ok with english-only key labels). So, any directions on where and how?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/16575) / [How do I add another keyboard layout to my ICS phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37999/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [External Keyboard Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo&hl=en), which is designed for bluetooth/usb keyboards but I believe it should work for the Chat's physical keyboard!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as I was learning Spanish. I was finding it almost impossible to key in the Spanish words using English text, one by one character. To get round this, I enabled two languages and therefore my phone now recognises both Spanish and English words and therefore I have no problems when switching from contacting colleagues to learning languages. To do this, go onto 'Settings', then 'Language and input'. Then scroll down to the option titled 'Samsung keyboard' and click the setting cog next to it. You should then see an option called 'Input languages' and from there, you should see a list of all the available languages on your phone. Simply check all the tickboxes of any languages you would like to use and then those languages will be enabled and you'll be able to type with them throughout any app on your phone. Hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: Does this work for the physical keyboard as well? Or is it only for on-screen touch keyboards?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, sorry. None of my devices have a physical keyboard. I just knew this was the method to do it on a standard Samsung device.

Comment: Then this most likely won't work for this question. It's just for on-screen keyboards, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *(at least was in the older and many newer versions of Android)* there's not a simple way *(to my knowledge - without adb/root)* to add language layouts. Even the common ones like Czech (QWERTZ) were missing for a long time.

For a simple solution you want to find packaged keyboard layouts (usually tiny .apk) but be wary of malicious ones.
If you want to create/import layout(s) I believe you should start looking into [Key Layout Files (.kl)](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files) but I personally haven't done it that way.

For me, **Raidsix Input Devices** (.apk (<100kB)) helped back in the day (from Google Play, when it was there year(s) ago). However it isn't available anymore and there seems to be no official or trustworthy way to obtain it.

*I still have it on my tablet so I shared it now with other tools to come in the future. [Link [Mediafire]](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/uhe0s5e4mfjl2/Tools)*

Comment: If you decinde to install Raidsix Input Devices then after the installation you'll just have more options in the System Settings for keyboard languages (layouts) (usually called 'Language and input') => The steps will be the same like other answers here afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can try a 3rd-party keyboard like [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms). It will allow you to use different keyboard layouts, including Russian. I think it has Czech (but probably not written in English).

[image]

Comment: This method doesn't work for galaxy chat since it has physical keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into input properties and choose the languages you want.

If you do not find the desired language then you must root your phone and use an app like [language enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam) from Google Play.

Answer (score -1):

aww you cant just make your physical keyboard to enter different language, You can try this:
-Use On Screen Keyboard
-download Google input for your desired language
-and change input method by long clicking any textfield

Comment: this isnt a right answer to any question @Dr.andro

Comment: There is no other option @cyberwalker

Comment: @Dr.Andro, I'm fairly certain there are other options. See my answer. You don't just have to take my word for it, you can look at the reviews for that app I linked.